# elasticsearch nested query returns only last 3 results

Tags: elasticsearch

We have the following `elasticsearch` mapping

```
{
    index: 'data',
    body: {
        settings: {
            analysis: {
                analyzer: {
                    lowerCase: {
                        tokenizer: 'whitespace',
                        filter: ['lowercase']
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        mappings: {
            // used for _all field
            _default_: {
                index_analyzer: 'lowerCase'
            },
            entry: {
                properties: {
                    id: { type: 'string', analyzer: 'lowerCase' },
                    type: { type: 'string', analyzer: 'lowerCase' },
                    name: { type: 'string', analyzer: 'lowerCase' },
                    blobIds: {
                        type: 'nested',
                        properties: {
                            id: { type: 'string' },
                            filename: { type: 'string', analyzer: 'lowerCase' }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and a sample document that looks like the following:

```
{
    "id":"5f02e9dae252732912749e13",
    "type":"test_type",
    "name":"test_name",
    "creationTimestamp":"2020-07-06T09:07:38.775Z",
    "blobIds":[
        {
            "id":"5f02e9dbe252732912749e18",
            "filename":"test1.csv"
        },
        {
            "id":"5f02e9dbe252732912749e1c",
            "filename":"test2.txt"
        },
        // removed in-between elements for simplicity
        {
            "id":"5f02e9dbe252732912749e1e",
            "filename":"test3.csv"
        },
        {
            "id":"5f02e9dbe252732912749e58",
            "filename":"test4.txt"
        },
        {
            "id":"5f02e9dbe252732912749e5a",
            "filename":"test5.csv"
        },
        {
            "id":"5f02e9dbe252732912749e5d",
            "filename":"test6.txt"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have the following ES query which is querying documents for a certain timerange based on the `creationTimestamp` field and then filtering the nested field `blobIds` based on a user query, that should match the `blobIds.filename` field.

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "creationTimestamp": {
                                    "gte": "2020-07-01T09:07:38.775Z",
                                    "lte": "2020-07-07T09:07:40.147Z"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "nested": {
                                "path": [
                                    "blobIds"
                                ],
                                "query": {
                                    "query_string": {
                                        "fields": [
                                            "blobIds.filename"
                                        ],
                                        "query": "*"
                                    }
                                },
                                // returns the actual blobId hit
                                // and not the whole array
                                "inner_hits": {}
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "query": {
                                "query_string": {
                                    "query": "+type:*test_type* +name:*test_name*"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "creationTimestamp": {
                "order": "asc"
            },
            "id": {
                "order": "asc"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The above entry is clearly matching the query. However, it seems like there is something wrong with the returned inner_hits, since I always get only the last 3 `blobIds` elements instead of the whole array that contains 24 elements, as can be seen below.

```
{
    "name": "test_name",
    "creationTimestamp": "2020-07-06T09:07:38.775Z",
    "id": "5f02e9dae252732912749e13",
    "type": "test_type",
    "blobIds": [
        {
            "id": "5f02e9dbe252732912749e5d",
            "filename": "test4.txt"
        },
        {
            "id": "5f02e9dbe252732912749e5a",
            "filename": "test5.csv"
        },
        {
            "id": "5f02e9dbe252732912749e58",
            "filename": "test6.txt"
        }
    ]
}
```

I find it very strange since I'm only doing a simple `*` query.

Using `elasticsearch` v1.7 and cannot update at the moment

Answer (score 0):

You should set the "size" of the nested query, as the default size is 3.

Read more about it here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/inner-hits.html#inner-hits-options

For your query, this will do:

```
...
{
                            "nested": {
                                "path": [
                                    "blobIds"
                                ],
                                "query": {
                                    "query_string": {
                                        "fields": [
                                            "blobIds.filename"
                                        ],
                                        "query": "*"
                                    }
                                },
                                // returns the actual blobId hit
                                // and not the whole array
                                "inner_hits": {
                                  "size": 100
                                }
                            }
                        }
...
```